# Inconsistent response from REST API when hosted on WSO2 API Manager 2.1

Tags: json, rest, request, wso2, response

We have a REST API hosted on WSO2 API Manager. When calling the API through WSO2, it sometimes returns the correct response, other times gives an error that the json object received is invalid. The log file shows that the json request object is not being submitted to the API at all.

Can anyone help out on how to resolve or troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Please enable wire logs and post logs in both working and not-working cases. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Do I need to install ESB?

Comment: No, APIM has the same thing.

Comment: I can see my error message in WSO2carbon file, however the logs are too long to paste here. In a successful request, i can see the https listener IO dispatcher reads the full object before the http sender starts:

Comment: Successful error message:
   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "{[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "  "CarDetails": {[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "    "CarNumber": "224353",[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}

Comment: Failed error message: HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "POST /api/RUF/PlatinumRufDues HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
   HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Authorization: Basic a682b246-a743-3bf4-b67c-3fea06d68315[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}

Comment: Need full log in each case. try https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Ok here's the link :  https://pastebin.com/61Yq5uJX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in the product log. The only difference I can see is the Activity Id is different in 2 requests, and it results in different responses.